# let expression in do causes error

Tags: haskell

```
import Text.JSON
import Control.Monad

data Status = Status { user :: String, text :: String } deriving Show

makeStatus :: JSObject JSValue -> Result Status
makeStatus tweet = let (!) = flip valFromObj in do
    userObject <- tweet ! "user"
    user <- userObject ! "screen_name"
    text <- tweet ! "text"
    return Status {user = user, text = text}
```

---

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( twitter.hs, interpreted )

twitter.hs:11:27:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Char]'
                with actual type `JSObject JSValue'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: JSObject JSValue
    In the `user' field of a record
    In the first argument of `return', namely
      `Status {user = user, text = text}'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Remove `let (!) = flip valFromObj in` and replace `tweet ! "user"` with `valFromObj "user" tweet` etc., everything is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused by [the monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction), which causes the type of `(!)` to be inferred as `JSObject JSValue -> String -> Result (JSObject JSValue)` because of its usage in

```
userObject <- tweet ! "user"
```

Adding a type signature fixes the problem.

```
makeStatus :: JSObject JSValue -> Result Status
makeStatus tweet = do
    userObject <- tweet ! "user"
    user <- userObject ! "screen_name"
    text <- tweet ! "text"
    return Status {user = user, text = text}
  where
    (!) :: JSON a => JSObject JSValue -> String -> Result a
    (!) = flip valFromObj
```